# Server Sockets in java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am creating an app for android which uses server socket over wifi-connectivity to exchange data between devices. I am able to send and receive data from server (hotspot) device.

My problem is that I want to send data to all other client devices as soon as it is received on server device from a client. Any IDEA how implement it??

Also the data I am exchanging is an Audio stream. Any suggestions will be appreciated..!!

Comment: You should send UDP data in broadcast and filter it on the receiving device. You could setup filter to each device through TCP packets sent by the server.

Comment: I am a noob in case of server sockets. Will you please eloborate?

Comment: Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: Well, I will have look at it!